# SSH: FTP created <user> logs into the wrong directory

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssh, chown, chgrp

Ok here's the deal - im new to SSH and have been googling around trying to figure this out.
Objective for me has been to create a FTP user that can login only to: /var/www/mydomain.com/ - however what I experience is that the user I create gets logged into /home/username and that I can actually browse all other folders on the server with this user.

These are the steps ive done - am I missing anything specific?

```
1. mkdir /var/www/mydomain.com
2. mkdir /var/www/mydomain.com/html
3. useradd <-username>
4. passwrd <-username>
5. chown –R <-username> /var/www/mydomain.com
5. groupadd <-groupname>
6. gpasswd -a <-username> <-groupname>
7. chgrp -R <-groupname> /var/www/mydomain.com
8. chmod -R g+rw /var/www/mydomain.com
```

Done on a Centos / linux installation.

Comment: What FTP server are you using?

Comment: Hi DerfK,

Not sure if I follow you. Im just logging onto the server with my created <user> + defined <password> via Filezilla. Im logging on without any issues, just that the root dir when logging in, isnt the one i've tried to set in my above steps

Comment: If you're not using SFTP, then there must be an FTP server installed in centos.  There are a number of different ones like proftpd, pureftpd, vsftpd, and so on.  Each one has different configuration.  Suku's answer will get your user to *start* in the mydomain.com directory, but they can leave the directory unless you configure the server to keep them there.

Comment: Hi DerfK - thanks for elaborating.
I can see when logging in that im using "vsFTPd". I just figured that it was possible to make that configuration in the process of creating user + group through SSH. Isnt there a SSH command that can take care of that? Or do I need to actually manually edit some local file related to the FTP configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useradd someuser -d /var/www/mydomain.com -s /bin/false
passwd someuser
```

**[EDIT]**

If I want to change already created user's home directory and shell, use following command:

```
sudo usermod someuser -d /home/someuser -s /bin/bash
```

If a user have `/bin/false` as the `shell`, that user can't login via ssh/Xorg or in another words, `/bin/false` is not a `login` shell

Comment: Hi Suku. Thanks a lot. I will just try this out. Wuld you be able to tell me what "-s /bin/false" <- does? Lets assume i've already created my user through basic "useradd <username>" - how would I go about changing that user to a new directory? In your example we're defining it from start (which I will do in the future), but just wondering what I do in the case im currently in, where ive created a user in /home/username - and want to change that folder to something else.

Comment: @user1231561 See the edit in answer. If this helped, please accept/upvote the answer.